# Bubble sort won't work(It's actually sort, I'm sorry)

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting

I have been learning C for like a week now. Today I have learned arrays and how to sort them using bubble sort, so I have written some code according to the book, it works great alone, but it won't work with a bigger program, the loops will just be skipped. I have tried to debug it, it works great until line 20 when for some reason outer will immediatly equal 9 and so inner will equal 10 and the program will move on. Here is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

int ctr; //loop counter
int idSearch; //Customer to look for (the key)
int found = 0; // 1 (true) if the customer is found

/* Defines the 10 elements in each of the parallel arrays */

int custID[10] = {313, 454, 502, 101, 892, 475, 792, 912, 343, 644};
float custBal[10] = {0.00, 45.43, 71.23, 301.56, 9.08, 192.41, 389.00, 229.67,
                     18.31, 59.54};
int tempID, inner, outer; // For sorting float temBal
tempID = inner = outer = 0;
float tempBal =0;

/* first, sort the arrays by customer ID */

for (outer=0; outer < 9; outer++);
    {
        for (inner = (outer+1); inner < 10; inner++)
            {
                if (custID[inner] < custID[outer])
                    {
                        tempID = custID[inner]; // must switch both arrays
                        tempBal = custBal[inner]; // or they won't be linked
                        custID[inner] = custID[outer];
                        custBal[inner] = custBal[outer];
                        custID[outer] = tempID;
                        custBal[outer] = tempBal;
                    }
            }
    }
/* Interact with the user looking to find a balance */

printf("**Customer Balance Lookup**\n");
printf("What is the customer's number? ");
    scanf(" %d", &idSearch);

/* Now look for the ID in the array */

for (ctr = 0; ctr <10; ctr++)
    {
        if (idSearch == custID[ctr]) //Do they match?
        {
            found = 1; // Yes, match flag is set to True
            break;
        }
        if (custID[ctr] > idSearch) // No need to keep searching
            {
                break;
            }
    }

// Once the loop has completed, the ID was either found if not

if (found)
    {
        if (custBal[ctr] > 100)
            {
                printf("\n**That customer's balance is $%.2f.**\n", custBal[ctr]);
                printf("No additional credit\n");
            } else {
                printf("\n**The customer's balance is good!**");
            }
    }else {         printf("\n**You have entered an incorrect customer ID.**");
        printf("\n ID %d was not found in the list.\n", idSearch);
    }

return (0);
```

}

Comment: Post declaration of `custID[]` and `custBal[]`.

Comment: @chux Can you please explain? I am quite new so I don't understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: Posted code lacks the declaration of of variables `custID[], custBal[], tempID , tempBal, outer`.  Post them as part of your question.  The current code, as is, certainly will not compile.

Comment: @chux Here is the full code, I didn't want to post it all to clutter the space, but since you asked for it  here it is.

Comment: Line 3 is `int main(void) {`. Please correctly identify the line where the error occurs.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens My bad, changed it.

Comment: Remove the semicolon on this line: `for (outer=0; outer < 9; outer++);
`. The semicolon is the statement being executed by the loop, rather than the following block. Setting a break point on this line should have identified the error quickly.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens yeah I just found out, I feel really embarrassed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you are trying to bubble sort the `custID` array, and in the process also sort the `custBal` array.  However, your logic for doing bubble sort is convoluted.  Try using this double `for` loop instead:

```
for (outer = 0; outer < ( n - 1 ); outer++) {
    for (d=inner = 0; inner < n - outer - 1; inner++) {
        if (custID[inner] > custID[inner+1])
        {
            tempID           = custID[inner];
            tempBal          = custBal[inner];
            custID[inner]    = custID[inner+1];
            custBal[inner]   = custBal[inner+1];
            custID[inner+1]  = tempID;
            custBal[inner+1] = tempBal;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What was the OP's logic for doing bubble sort? It didn't look like it was implementing bubble sort to me.

Comment: The logic was a tangled mess.  This is why I just started from scratch.

Comment: I believe that your code and mine do the exact same thing, but in my code inner always = outer+1 so I don't need to type [inner+1] like you do when switching places

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Take your time. :)

Comment: @H.Malkawi no, `inner` *starts* at `outer+1` but soon gets out of sync as it increments. What you have implemented is *not* a bubble sort, although it's as slow as one.

Comment: @MarkRansom Many thanks for this detective work.  His code looked so far from a standard bubble sort that I chose to abandon it completely without even checking it.

Comment: yeah exactly if outer is 0, why would I compare 0 to  0? so inner starts at 1

Comment: and then it will be 0 compared to 2 3.... after the 2nd loop is don't outer will become 1, 1 will be compared 2 3.... and the loops keeps going on. It works and I just tested it out. If you can improve it I would be more than pleased to see my code improved.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen looks like I was wrong, I am sorry. I've looked up some source code, and sort selection looks more like mine, are there any resources that state the difference between bubble and sort selection?

Comment: Just try Googling for these two algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

I am really embarrassed to write this, but after 30 mins of looking through my code, going through it line by line, I found a semi colon at the end of line 20 `for (outer=0; outer < 9; outer++);`

Thank you guys for trying to help me I really appreciate it.

Comment: Sorry to crash your party, but your logic is wrong.

Comment: How so? The arrays have 10 values each. outer sort and inner sort are used to compare the values, the outer value is kept constant during each pass while the inner one is changing, if one meets the requirements( inner smaller than outer) then it will be switched from the two arrays since they are linked together.

Comment: Your current logic does not swap values, nor does it do bubble sort correctly.

Comment: Can you please explain that using my code? I have tried it and it works perfectly. If I am missing anything point it out please

Comment: It certainly does look more like a Selection Sort than a bubble sort:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort - in a bubble sort the only comparisons and swaps are between adjacent elements.

Comment: @moreON What basically is going on is that it compares the first array custID, if it makes changes it will also make the same changes to the custBal array (to sort them). I hope that gives you a clear understanding

Comment: @moreON is correct, your sort resembles a Selection sort more than it does a Bubble sort - although it performs many more swaps than necessary. Just because you've successfully implemented a sort doesn't mean it's the right one.

Comment: @MarkRansom looks like I was wrong, I am sorry. I've looked up some source code, and sort selection looks more like mine, are there any resources that state the difference between bubble and sort selection?

Comment: @H.Malkawi Wikipedia has generally good articles on simple algorithms. Try to understand both bubble and selection sort. If you can perform them manually, that's usually helpful.Once you understand both sorts, you should understand the difference between them. ...  If you need entertainment: watch the Hungarian folk dancing sorts on YouTube.